# restriction to image dimension asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, restriction, image-size

I want to make restriction to the dimensions of the asp.net C# image.

I have image1:

```
ImageButton ib = (ImageButton)sender;
Image1.ImageUrl = ib.ImageUrl;
```

Also I have:

```
Image tempImage = new Image();
tempImage.ImageUrl = ib.ImageUrl;
```

next I am setting dimensions of image1

```
Image1.Width = Math.Max(tempImage.Width, 1000);
```

Here I get compiler error: math.max has bad parameters.
So the aim is to not allow the width of image be bigger than 1000.
How this can be done?

Comment: Have you looked at MSDN for Math.Max Method have you thought about a much safer method Math.Min ...? be sure that you are also passing the same datatype for both params

Comment: i also have tried to compare two widthes                     if(tempImage.Width > tempImage2.Width), here the compiler error also gives an error saying tempImage.Width method returns System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit

Comment: Can you show the full code where the method as well as the error is happening..

Comment: Image1.Width = Math.Max(tempImage.Width, 1000);

Comment: You've got the answer: "tempImage.Width method returns System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit". Look that up on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.unit.value.aspx and find that you need to use the `Value` property to get the `double` value.

Comment: look at this example it may give you a better idea of what you need to do..
http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/graph/programmatically-resizing-an-image

Answer (score 0):

Math.Max expects Double

try casting your params to (double) like this

```
  int maxValue = 1000;
  var convDouble = Convert.ToDouble((double)tempImage.Width,(double)maxValue);
```

for starters look at the code above Math.Max expects the following

```
   Math.Max(double , double);
```

also in this line in your code

```
Image tempImage = new Image();
tempImage.ImageUrl = ib.ImageUrl
```

why not create the tempImage then set the max width
then call 
    `temp.ImageUrl = ib.Image()`;

Comment: compiler gets error: cannot convert tempImage.Width to double. You are right, but I think it doesnt' matter what is first and what is second. The program works anyway.

Comment: because you have to cast the Image Width to a Double.. quest is is it working have you tried what I have done in the example where I am using var convDouble..?